# Matching hashes in C

Tags: c, hash

I am fairly new to C and am currently practicing by writing a program which that allows users to search for hashes written in a text file. I have come up with the following program:

HashMatch.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Declaring Functions
int searchstringinfile(char *string, char *filename);
void UsageInfo(char *filename);

//Display usage info on arguments for program
void UsageInfo(char *filename) {
    printf("Usage: %s <file> <string>\n", filename);

}

int searchstringinfile(char *filename, char *string) {
    //Define File
    FILE *userfile;

    int linenumber = 1;
    int search_result = 0;
    char temp[10000];

    //Error handling for invalid file
    if((userfile = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
        return(-1);
    }


    //Matching words line-by-line
    while(fgets(temp, 10000, userfile) != NULL) {
        if((strstr(temp, string)) != NULL) {
        //Display line in which matched word is found
            printf("A match found on line: %d\n", linenumber);
            printf("\n%s\n", temp);
            search_result++;
    }
    linenumber++;
}


    // Display message if no matches are found
    if(search_result == 0) {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }

    //Closes the file.
    if(userfile) {
        fclose(userfile);
    }
    return(0);
}


//main function.
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int result, errcode;
    //Display format for user to enter arguments and
    //End program if user does not enter exactly 3 arguments
    if(argc < 3 || argc > 3) {
        UsageInfo(argv[0]);
        exit(1);
}


    system("cls");
//Pass command line arguments into searchstringinfile
    result = searchstringinfile(argv[1], argv[2]);
//Display error message
        if(result == -1) {
            perror("Error");
            printf("Error number = %d\n", errcode);
            exit(1);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

I have also come up with a file containing one string and one hash:

Hashtext.txt

```
$1$$t8TX0OHN6Wsx6vlPZNKik1
Ice-Cream
I SCREAM FOR Ice-Cream !
```

If I were to search for the word Ice-Cream as such:

```
./test hashtext Ice-Cream
```

I am able to find lines containing said word :

```
A match found on line: 2

Ice-Cream

A match found on line: 3

I SCREAM FOR Ice-Cream !
```

However if I were to search for the hash in the text , I am unable to do so.
Could anyone enlighten me on why I am unable to search for the hash and guide me through the steps to allow me to do so ?

Thank You.

Comment: maybe hash doesn't occur?

Comment: The issue seems to be on the way you call your program with the hash. Try to print to input search string to check it.

Comment: You need to escape $ if it is part of your command line arguments

Comment: Awesome ! There is an issue with how the program handles '$'. It prints out "3242t8TX0OHN6Wsx6vlPZNKik1"                                                      instead of "$1$$t8TX0OHN6Wsx6vlPZNKik1"                                                  What can I do to overcome this ?                                                                           Edit: Formatting and character length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hash string has '$'s in it. Bash considers it as a special character. Special characters need to be escaped in order to remove the special meaning of these characters.

Depending on the situation you can do either of the following to handle them:

1. Escape the special characters individually using `\`. Your input string would look like `\$1\$\$t8TX0OHN6Wsx6vlPZNKik1`.
2. Escape the special characters from the entire string using `'`. Your input string would look like `'$1$$t8TX0OHN6Wsx6vlPZNKik1'`.
3. Load the string from `stdin` by redirection. However, you'll need to edit your program for this. You won't need to escape the characters.

Here's the comprehensive list of many special characters in bash: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/upt/ch08_19.htm

Answer (score 0):

From comments you seem to agree your command lines have $, you dont need to handle it in code,rather while passing it from shell you need to escape them  like:

```
./test hashtext \$1\$\$t8TX0OHN6Wsx6vlPZNKik1
```

Comment: Awesome ! Thank you. I'll figure out a way to add the backslash to each occurence of '$' :)